# Creating a large table in rst with nested column headers and getting the latex rendering to wrap the header text

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I need to create a wide table, like the example below, that will span the whole pdf page after it's rendered in latex.

The problem I'm having is that the column header text is not wrapping to fit the width of the column.

```
+----------+--------------------------------+------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Header 1 | Long Header 2 that should wrap | Common column Header 3 | Header 4 | Header 5 | Header 6 | Header 7 | Header 8 |
|          |                                +-----------+------------+          |          |          |          |          |
|          |                                | Header 3a | Header 3b  |          |          |          |          |          |
+==========+================================+===========+============+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+
| Value 1  | Value 2 does actually wrap     | Value 3a  | Value 3b   | Value 4  | Value 5  | Value 6  | Value 7  | Value 8  |
+----------+--------------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Shows up like this:

[image: Header 2 encroaches into 3rd column]

I've tried adjusting column widths using the `.. tabularcolumns:: |p{0.1 \textwidth|...` directive, but it didn't seem to fix the encroaching header text problem.

If I remove the "Common column Header 3" (second example below) I get the desired wrapping header text behavior, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with that part:

```
+----------+--------------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Header 1 | Long Header 2 that should wrap | Header 3a | Header 3b  | Header 4 | Header 5 | Header 6 | Header 7 | Header 8 |
|          |                                |           |            |          |          |          |          |          |
|          |                                |           |            |          |          |          |          |          |
+==========+================================+===========+============+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+
| Value 1  | Value 2 does actually wrap     | Value 3a  | Value 3b   | Value 4  | Value 5  | Value 6  | Value 7  | Value 8  |
+----------+--------------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Looks like this:

[image: Desired text wrapping behavior for Header 2]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: While not exactly perfect (see 3/3a/3b), a minimal example wraps headers for me nicely. I'd guess that you did something with your LaTeX setup that breaks the table.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEJdX.png

Comment: This seems like a bug in sphinx. I've filed an [issue on their GitHub page](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3288), hopefully someone is aware of a workaround in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is with the way the LaTeX `multirow` package is used. Sphinx produces this kind of mark-up:

```
   ...&\multirow{2}{*}{\relax \sphinxstylethead{\relax 
   Long Header 2 that should wrap
   \unskip}\relax \unskip}\relax &...
```

but the `multirow` documentation says that `*` indicates to use `the text parameter’s natural width` and I don't know but perhaps this does not play well with `tabulary` rendering of the table. The alternative is to indicate an explicit width, which Sphinx can not guess in general: however it possibly could in case of presence of `..tabularcolumns` as it would have the information then.

`multirow` is old package but has had recent update in september 2016 to `v2.0` which introduces new possibility `=` for this parameter

> to indicate that the specified width of the column in which the `\multirow` entry is set should be used.

I have tried manually inserting the `=` rather than `*` and it fixed your first example. As Sphinx LaTeX writer seemingly always uses `\multirow` with the `{*}`, I can propose this hack. Put in your `conf.py`

```
latex_elements = {
    'preamble': r'\let\oldmultirow\multirow\def\multirow#1#2{\oldmultirow{#1}{=}}',
 }
```

and make sure you are using a fully updated TeX installation as you need multirow 2.0. This means you need TeXLive 2016 up-to-date or MikTeX on Windows, up-to-date.

Sphinx can possibly consider using `=` but this will work only for users with such up-to-date TeX installations. Maybe there are better ways, but this one worked for me on your example 1 (no need then for `..tabularcolumns::` directive), on a4 paper and with Sphinx 1.5.2. (the table is longer than text linewidth)

[image]

Comment: thanks for feedback... since I have gained a bit more experience with this recent `=` specifier for multirow. As explains in its docs, the column specifier should directly or indirectly give an indication of the column width. When you use a ``.. tabularcolumns`` directive with a ``p{Xcm}`` (or a ``L`` if the table is short enough for Sphinx to use ``tabulary`` environment) it is ok. But when Sphinx uses a ``tabular`` or ``longtable`` environment with ``l`` specifiers,  the `=` does not work well. As a simpler alternative to ``tabularcolumns`` mark-up, Sphinx 1.6 will allow the Docutils ...

Comment: ... ``:widths:`` [option](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/changes.html#features-added), and this is also good context for the multirow with ``=`` specifier. In your example you could use then something like ``:widths: 10,25,10,10,10,10,10,10,10`` avoiding LaTeX markup (and HTML build will get same proportions).

Answer (score 5):

It's not a perfect solution, but you should be able to manually force the text to the next line with the newline character `|` (pipe and 2 spaces) like so:

```
+---------------------------
| |  Header    | |  Header |
| |  1         | |  2      |
+==============+===========+
|  value 1     | value 2   |
+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately that works for the second example, but not the first.